# BigQuery "resources exceeded"; what could be the culprit?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm learning BigQuery with the new [Github dataset](https://github.com/blog/2201-making-open-source-data-more-available) and my queries to the commits dataset keep failing due to resources exceeded. I trimmed down the SQL to this code and it still fails:

```
SELECT
  commit,
  FIRST(repo_name) AS repo_name,
  FIRST(author.email) AS author_email,
  FIRST(author.time_sec) AS time,
  SUM(LENGTH(message)) AS len_commit_msg,
  COUNT(difference.new_path) AS num_files
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits]
GROUP BY
  commit
ORDER BY
  repo_name,
  time
```

The dataset in question is large (150m rows) and what I want is just a list of commits with basic information about them (length of commit message and number of changed files).

Is there something particularly wrong in this example? I've tried changing the SUM(LENGTH(message)) part and the COUNT() to no avail. Or is the sort part a no-no for big query?

I also checked the previous "resources exceeded" questions and the answers relate to problems with PARTITION, JOIN, or GROUP EACH BY, which I have avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORDER BY is expensive - try without it

Comment: Additionally, if you only care about the first N ordered results, add `LIMIT N`, and the query will succeed.

Comment: What Jordan say - you probably don't care about sorting 150 million rows, so instead of sorting the whole result set - LIMIT 100.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed ORDER BY is the culprit. The dataset appeared to already be sorted by those variables, but due to de way bigquery works this probably can't be exploited.